# Проблема с линковкой программы и SDL_image (CMake)

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl2

Мой CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5) 
project(sdlsand)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(sdlsand src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(sdlsand ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES})
```

find_package() не нашёл файлов конфигурации SDL_image:

```
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SDL2_image" with
  any of the following names:

    SDL2_imageConfig.cmake
    sdl2_image-config.cmake
```

Перерыл весь интернет, не нашёл решения. SDL_image у меня установлен через MSYS2 как надо, даже переустанавливал. Как слинковать SDL_image с программой через CMake?

Comment: Мне кажется, что вам сначала стоит разобраться, какие команды компилятору для сборки вы хотите получить. А зачем уже писать и отлаживать систему сборки посредством cmake для получения нужных вам команд, если вообще захочется с ним связываться.

Comment: @user7860670, разве CMake нужен не для автоматизации сборки и её упрощения? как по мне, это тоже самое, что и "если хочешь начать писать на питоне - выучи ассемблер"

Comment: Для автоматизации CMake можно использовать, только "автоматизация" не предполагает отсутствие необходимости разбираться в настройках среды и компилятора. Выхлоп CMake - по сути текст с командами, которые в любом случае придется проверять. А если не знаете, что хотите получить в результате, то он не поможет. В плане упрощения не особо полезен, ведь это язык крайне не консистентный, с тенденцией наваливать глобальные переменные, еще и с ограниченными средствами отладки.

Comment: *"если хочешь начать писать на питоне - выучи ассемблер"* - это, в целом, верное утверждение. А то некоторые по курсам попрыгают и даже побитовые операции вгоняют их в ступор.

Comment: Тут я соглашусь, но насчет питона и ассемблера немного иначе: питон высокоуровневый язык, он все что можно облегчает, и без костылей не даст доступ к низкоуровневым операциям и т.д. Я думаю, что достаточно будет знать принцип работы указателей, для обращения к функциям WinAPI например.